# Facebook with PHP API - Infinite Session

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, infinite

i have looked over the internet on some information about this but all that i've found is for the SDK version 2.X.X, now with the 3.0.0 version it ain't working.

What i need is to get the user info and use it as a server to be posting anytime without rellying on cookies.

Any idea of how to do this? The old tutorials sugests something like this:

```
$facebook->getSession()
```

and on the sessions, i would get the keys but this method doesnt exists anymore. Any idea how to get the sessions keys and to re-use it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an "infinite" session, ask for the `offline_access` permission. From there, you'll have to take the `access_token` from the session and store it in a database.

Comment: I have the access token, now where i set it later after i get it from the database? thats my doubt...

Answer (score 0):

The SDK provided by Facebook for PHP is intended to be called and utilized while a user browses your site - actions that perform facebook API calls without the users direct involvement require something more robust that uses the same approach but with saved tokens and initiated by cronjobs or background processes.

The oAuth 2.0 flow for validation and granting permissions is detailed in Facebook's documentation.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

You can perform the logic described here manually without even using the SDK using a standard HTTP request library like CURL.  Basically what's entailed is sending a request to facebook when the user first looks to grant access, at which point the browser should redirect fully to the FB Login/permissions dialog.  It is in this query that you specify what permissions you will require.  You can use the `redirect_uri` parameter to point this back to an endpoint in your application that then takes the data Facebook returns, sends it back for an access token, and then saves that final oAuth token to a file or database row associated with that user.

For the kind of actions you have described, you'll need to request the `offline_access` permission when you make your URL call to Facebook.  This generates a token that will be permanently valid until the user revokes its permissions in their facebook account using the 'Aps' interface.

You can learn more about oAuth here:
http://oauth.net/2/

I also highly suggest subscribing to Facebook's Developer RSS feed.  They very regularly make huge shifts in how they operate their API and typically only announce them there.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/feed

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i've readed that and i cant get into a solution using the faceook-php sdk. I've managed to pull out a infinite session with the flash-facebook api but now i need it to work on php, do you know where i can find any example codes?